# pipe ls output to one line perl script

Tags: perl, bash, solaris

Command

```
ls | perl -lane "print $ARGV[0]"
```

I tried to pipe the ls output to one line perl script and print the argument but I am getting the following output. The perl version used is 5.8.4 built for sun4-solaris-64int.

Result

```
ARRAY(0x229e8)
ARRAY(0x229e8)
ARRAY(0x229e8)
ARRAY(0x229e8)
ARRAY(0x229e8)
ARRAY(0x229e8)
ARRAY(0x229e8)
ARRAY(0x229e8)
ARRAY(0x229e8)
ARRAY(0x229e8)
```

what changes required to list the files in the directory?

Comment: In Unix, double quotes in a shell command interpolate variables. Since there's probably not a variable named `ARGV` defined in your shell environment, your code is equivalent to `... | perl -lane 'print [0]'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current line gets assigned to `$_`, so you want something like

```
ls | perl -lne 'print $_'
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if `ls` here is a mere example, it be worth mentioning that there is no any reason to pipe it’s output to Perl. To obtain ls-like listing (no dot files) you can use:

```
$ perl -e 'my @f = glob("*"); print join("\n", @f) . "\n"'
```

or

```
$ perl -e 'my @f = <*>; print join("\n", @f) . "\n"'
```

Note that the second doesn’t accept variable substitution (`@f = <$mypattern>` is wrong).